# Why must be the number of the vertical LEDs a multiple of 8?

Tags: arduino, teensy

I'm going to build a LED-Wall which i will control via 4 teensy micro controllers. Everywere I read the vertical number of my LEDs has to be a multiple of 8? Does it really have to be so?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The number **8** is the factor of number of output pins in a [port](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation) of most digital electronics component (shifters, drivers etc) which assumes a output word to be `8 bits`.
A port in a general purpose MCU or MPU will have 8 pins.

Thus the whole available pins can be utilised without wastage.

ATmega168P/328P in arduino, has 3 ports. `PORTB`, `PORTC`, and `PORTD`.